# How to disable Flash and Java element context menu in Cocoa WebView

Tags: cocoa, flash, webview, contextmenu

The WebUIDelegate

```
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
```

does not get called for Flash and Java elements.

Any chance to disable/customize those ones too (without parsing the received page and injecting java script code)?

Comment: You can always just disable plugins if you don't need other plugins.

Comment: I do not want to disable the elements, just their context menu as the topic says